# Permutation algorithm using an explicit stack

Tags: python, stack, sequence, permutation

I was reading the chapter of stack in my book and there is this question in the exercise :

```
Describe a nonrecursive algorithm for enumerating all permutations of the
numbers {1, 2, . . . , n} using an explicit stack.
```

Understanding and implementing the recursive algorithm was easy. But I am not getting how to implement it with an explicit stack. What would be a possible solution for this? If you think that the hints would be self sufficient to solve this, please provide them only so that I can give it one more try!!

Comment: Basically, you need to find an iterative method of doing this (using `for` loops, for example).

Comment: Also, what do you mean by explicit stack?

Comment: By explicit stack, I mean a stack defined by the user, instead of an implicit one that the program uses in case of recursion.

Comment: What operations would be allowed on the stack? Python doesn't appear to have a `swap()` operation, just `append()` and `pop()`.

Comment: @mbomb007 there is no such restriction that you can't build another definition as per your need.

Comment: Not sure if this question is a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479779/generate-permutation-using-a-single-stack